# Pull settings from package options as variables

Tags: captions, packages, sidenotes

Sorry if it is a simple matter, but I am quite new to advanced LaTeX (before I only used preset styles and did simple things), and I couldn't find an answer after ~30 min of searching.

I want to use Harvard PhD thesis style with `sidenotes` package. By default Harvard PhD uses `caption` package to manage figure captions, but `sidenotes` introduces more styles (e.g. for full width figures, side captions and margin figures). I am trying to make all captions look the same. Here are my settings for `caption`:

```
\RequirePackage[labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small},
justification=RaggedRight,margin=0pt]{caption}
```

Then in order to make `sidenotes` captions look the same, I go through all of styles and set the same settings:

```
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small}}
```

But I make double work here and if I need to change one thing, I would have to change it in many places. I realize that I can define a variable which would contain style settings and then just pass it to all of these styles, but I wonder if I can instead pull the settings I already defined from `caption` package and pass them to `sidenotes` styles.

I guess in a more general form my question is: how I can pull already defined package options to use same options in another place.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options used for each package are stored in a csname of the form `opt@name.sty`

so for example

```
\RequirePackage[labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small},
justification=RaggedRight,margin=0pt]{caption}

\expandafter \show\csname opt@caption.sty\endcsname
```

shows that opt@caption.sty has the value you want.

```
> \opt@caption.sty=macro:
->labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small},justification=RaggedRight,margin=
0pt.
```

You can iterate through such a comma separated list of options using the standard latex `\@for` or any other list processing macro you need.

Answer (score 3):

The caption package offers a documented [1] way to store and recall options with `\captionsetup[<name>]{<options>}` and `\captionsetup{options=<name>}`. A simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[waddehaddeduda]{labelfont=bf,textfont=it}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{options=waddehaddeduda}
\caption{Another caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This works nested, too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[waddehaddeduda]{labelfont=bf,textfont=it}
\captionsetup[test]{options=waddehaddeduda,font=large}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{options=test}
\caption{Another caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So your code could be transformed into something like this:

```
\RequirePackage[justification=RaggedRight,margin=0pt]{caption}
\captionsetup[sidenotes]{labelfont={sf,bf,small},textfont={sf,small}}
...
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{options=sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{options=sidenotes}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{options=sidenotes}
```

[1] Yes, I have to admit that it's really poorly documented, it's only listed in the list of options in the appendix A.1.